# Meshing colors together

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering why something as a simple navigation bar seemed to pop out when mine stayed stale and seemingly unimportant. When looking at a site, www.teamliquid.com, I found that there navigation bar meshed a lighter and darker version of the color in a way that wasn't noticeable but really made the bars pop out to your eyes.

Even on the left with the small forum banners, "News" and "general", they mesh a lighter and darker version of the blue so seamlessly. I can't find anywhere on how to do this, and when inspecting the elements and checking their image resources it doesn't seem they do this through graphics either.

Can anyone explain how to do this using html or css? Do I need to use jQuery?

Comment: -1: You only mentioned jQuery once. Please mention it at least four times for an upvote.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by that, but I mentioned it because I'm learning it at the moment and wondered If i just needed to get farther in that to learn to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done with an image. You can right click->inspect element and identify things like this on your own in the future :) Just check and see if it's using a bg-image.

In this case, the image is: http://www.teamliquid.net/mirror/layout/SidebarSprite5.png

Comment: Ahh thanks. I wasn't sure on how to find whether it was an image or not. But now that i'm sure it was able to find it. Appreciate it.